# Concept behind the table BigQuery for data in GA360

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, flatten

There are some questions about bigquery that I would like to clarify for.

As far as I understand, the default table is based on session level, and it is a nested table which collect the hit based information. And in my understanding, the table can be sth roughly like this:

```
Session data        date                     Hits
  Session1       2018-09-20      types         time       hitNumber
                                 event1        00:01          1
                                 event2        00:02          3

  Session2       2018-09-21      types         time       hitNumber
                                 event1        00:01          1
                                 event3        00:04          2
```

And when I have to extract the hit based information e.g event types, what I have to do is to flatten in legacy or unnest in standard to flatten the data so as to make it like this:

```
 Session data        date          Hits.types      Hits.time     Hits.hitNumber
  Session1        2018-09-20         event1          00:01           1
  Session1        2018-09-20         event2          00:02           3
  Session2        2018-09-21         event1          00:01           1
  Session2        2018-09-21         event3          00:04           2
```

And here comes to my questions:

1. Did I understand the overall concept correctly?
2. If I understand it correctly, then we have sth which is like hits.page.pagePath. Does it means that under the hits there is another table which save the page information for every hits?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In BigQuery’s Google Analytics schema, each record represents a
   session. The fullVisitorId and visitId, together, form a unique key
   for each session

> so your 1st understanding is correct

1. Once you start seeing GA data in BigQuery, you will notice that it
   is the raw analytics data, at the hit level (that is, at pageview,
   event, and e-commerce transaction level rather than session or user
   level).

Comment: Hi, #1 you're correct. #2 yes, the tables go deep a few dimensions, basically each hit can have a series of parameters that are either filled by the user's browser or set by you when installing ga in the front end. If you want to go deeper in these look for the measurement protocol (or try out this tool https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ for fun).